# Why my tablayout row content doesnt fit the screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-tablayout, android-jetpack-compose-modifier

I created a TabLayout on one screen in Jetpack compose and created two pages.I created a TabLayout on one screen in Jetpack compose and created two pages, but there is a problem: even if the content on one screen fits perfectly on the screen, the other tab does not fit exactly on the screen and there are gaps, it seems like it is taking the size of the screen that takes up the largest space as a reference. . I tried to adjust it using padding, modifier etc. but I couldn't. Can you help me with this? here are my codes

**IngredientDetailscreen**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun IngredientDetailScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    nutritionDetail: NutritionItem?,
    state: IngredientDetailScreenState,
    onChangePortion: (String) -> Unit,
    onChangePortionName: (String) -> Unit,
    editList: (NutritionItem?, ArrayList<NutritionItem>) -> Unit,
    favouriteItem: (ContentDetailFavouriteRequestModel) -> Unit
) {

    val onlyNumericPattern = remember { Regex("^\\d+\$") }
    var shouldShowPicker by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val modalBottomSheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)

    val list = listOf(
        "BESİN DEĞERLERİ",
        "TARİFİ"
    )

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = Unit,
        block = {

        })


    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            ListSheet(
                nutritionValueListSize = state.foodRecipe?.ingredients?.size,
                ingredientList = state.foodRecipe?.ingredients?.map { it.toUiModel() }
            )
        },
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
    ) {
        Scaffold(topBar = {
            TopBar(
                onBackClick = { navHostController.popBackStack() },
                saveFavourite = { isClickFvrt ->

                },
                screenDescription = "Girişi Düzenle"
            )
        }) { padding ->


            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(padding)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                AddIngredientItem(
                    startPadding = 15.dp,
                    endPadding = 15.dp,
                    imgSize = 75.dp,
                    nameFontSize = 17.sp,
                    nameMaxLines = 2,
                    nameFontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    image = nutritionDetail?.ntrImg ?: "",
                    ntrName = nutritionDetail?.ntrName ?: "",
                    kcal = nutritionDetail?.ntrKcal,
                    unit = nutritionDetail?.ntrUnit ?: "",
                    onClick = {}
                )
                if (state.response?.foodRecipe != null && state.response.foodRecipe.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Column {
                        TabLayout(
                            state = state,
                            tabList = list,
                            pagerCount = 2,
                            nutritionDetail = nutritionDetail,
                            navHostController = navHostController,
                            shouldShowPicker = {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(
                                        ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }

                } else {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp))

                    NutritionValueContent(
                        hasPayment = state.response?.hasPayment,
                        kcal = nutritionDetail?.ntrKcal,
                        mainNutritionValues = state.mainNutritionValues,
                        nutritionValueList = state.nutritionValues ?: arrayListOf(),
                        onClickImg = {
                            navHostController.navigate(RegisterScreen.SignUpPaymentScreen.route)
                        },
                        name = state.response?.nutritionalValues?.find { it.seqId == 1 }?.name ?: ""
                    )
                }

                if (shouldShowPicker)
                    ListItemPickerComponent(
                        onConfirmClick = { portionName, index ->
                            shouldShowPicker = false
                            onChangePortionName(portionName)
                        },
                        onCancelClick = {
                            shouldShowPicker = false
                        },
                        valueList = state.nutritionValuesNames,
                        value = state.nutritionValuesNames.first(),
                    )

                BaseBottomSheet(content = {
                    SheetContent(
                        saveRecipe = {
                            val ntrItem = NutritionItem(
                                ntrId = nutritionDetail?.ntrId,
                                ntrImg = nutritionDetail?.ntrImg,
                                ntrName = nutritionDetail?.ntrName,
                                ntrUnit = nutritionDetail?.ntrUnit,
                                ntrKcal = nutritionDetail?.ntrKcal,
                                ntrUnitId = nutritionDetail?.ntrUnitId,
                                value = state.portion
                            )
                            //editList(ntrItem,state.selectedNtrList)
                            navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.apply {
                                set(ADD_INGREDIENT, ntrItem)
                            }
                            navHostController.popBackStack()
                        },
                        choosePortion = {
                            shouldShowPicker = !shouldShowPicker
                        },
                        onChangeText = { portion ->
                            if (portion.isEmpty() || portion.matches(onlyNumericPattern))
                                onChangePortion(portion)
                        },
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                        _portionName = state.portionName ?: "",
                        _portion = state.portion ?: ""
                    )
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TabLayout**

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TabLayout(
    state: IngredientDetailScreenState,
    tabList: List<String>,
    pagerCount: Int,
    nutritionDetail: NutritionItem?,
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    shouldShowPicker: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = pagerCount)

    Tabs(pagerState = pagerState, tabList)
    TabsContent(
        pagerState = pagerState,
        state = state,
        nutritionDetail = nutritionDetail,
        navHostController = navHostController,
        shouldShowPicker = shouldShowPicker
    )

}
```

**TabsContent**

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TabsContent(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    state: IngredientDetailScreenState,
    nutritionDetail: NutritionItem?,
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    shouldShowPicker: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {


    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->

        when (page) {
            0 -> {
                Column {
                    NutritionValueContent(
                        hasPayment = state.response?.hasPayment,
                        kcal = nutritionDetail?.ntrKcal,
                        mainNutritionValues = state.mainNutritionValues,
                        nutritionValueList = state.nutritionValues ?: arrayListOf(),
                        onClickImg = {
                            navHostController.navigate(RegisterScreen.SignUpPaymentScreen.route)
                        },
                        name = state.response?.nutritionalValues?.find { it.seqId == 1 }?.name
                            ?: "",
                    )
                }
            }
            1 -> {

                var isClickList by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                    Column() {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp))
                        FoodPreparation(
                            cookingTime = state.foodRecipe?.foodCookingtime,
                            cookingTimeImg = R.drawable.ic_cooking,
                            peopleCount = state.foodRecipe?.peopleCount,
                            peopleCountImg = R.drawable.ic_fork_and_spoon,
                            preparationTime = state.foodRecipe?.foodPreparetime,
                            preparationTimeImg = R.drawable.ic_preparation
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp))
                        Divider(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp))
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp))
                        IngredientHeader(
                            title = "Malzemeler (${state.foodRecipe?.ingredients?.size ?: ""})",
                            detailTxt = "Liste",
                            onClickDetailTxt = {
                                isClickList = !isClickList
                                shouldShowPicker(isClickList)
                            }
                        )

                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                                .padding(15.dp)
                        ) {
                            state.foodRecipe?.ingredients?.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                                val layoutPadding =
                                    if (index == state.foodRecipe.ingredients.size - 1) 0.dp else 10.dp

                                HealthItem(
                                    layoutPadding = layoutPadding,
                                    width = 105.dp,
                                    imageSize = 103.dp,
                                    itemId = item.unitId,
                                    articleTypeId = item.nutritionId,
                                    itemName = item.nutritionName ?: "",
                                    image = item.image ?: "",
                                    detailText = item.unitName,
                                    detailTextColor = MaterialTheme.colors.grayColor,
                                    additionalImg = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_home_content_recipe),
                                    content = {},
                                    onClick = { itemId, articleTypeId, itemName, image ->

                                    },
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp),
                            text = "Tarifi",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
                        )
                        RecipeContent(
                            state.foodRecipe?.content
                        )
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**this is fit screen**

screenshots:

[image]

**this is not fit screen as you can see the spaces**

[image]

Why do gaps occur like this? I want it to start from the top but I couldn't, I don't think it's related to modifier or anything else but I'm not sure.

Comment: Give ```Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())``` for the second screeen root element

Comment: it doesn't work